# Linear Algebra theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following theorem:

Let $F \subseteq E$ be fields, and let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . . , \alpha_m$ be vectors in $F^n$. A vector $v \in F^n$ is in the subspace of $F^n$ spanned by the $α_i$ if and only if v is in the subspace of $E^n$ spanned by the $α_i$.

The "only if" part is easy because of this:

If $x$ exists in the subspace of $F^n$ spanned by the $\alpha_i$, then $x=c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_m\alpha_m$, where $c_i\in F$. But $F \subseteq E$, so $c_i\in E$ and it follows that $x$ exists in the subspace of $E^n$ spanned by the $\alpha_i$.

The "if" part is troubling me. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider what the problem asks for. The hard part is the following. Suppose the field $E$ is an extension of the field $F$. Suppose $v, \alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{m} \in F^{n}$. Suppose $v$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_{i}$ **with coefficients in $E$**. Is it also true that $v$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_{i}$ **with coefficients in $F$**? And the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "if" part.

Write
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}v_{1}\\ \vdots \\ v_{n}\end{bmatrix} \in F^{n}
$$
and
$$
\alpha_{i} =
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{1i} \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_{ni}\end{bmatrix} \in F^{n}
$$
and consider the two matrices with coefficients in $F$
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{11} & \dots & \alpha_{1m}\\
&\ddots\\
\alpha_{n1} & \dots & \alpha_{nm}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} & \alpha_{11} & \dots & \alpha_{1m}\\
&&\ddots\\
v_{n} &\alpha_{n1} & \dots & \alpha_{nm}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The hypothesis that you can write $v$ as a linear combination, with coefficients in $E$, of the $\alpha_{i}$, tells you that the (column) ranks of $A$ and $C$ are the same. But then, reversing the argument, this tells you that $v$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_{i}$ with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: Why do the fact that $v$ is a linear combination, with coefficients in $E$, of the $\alpha_i$ tells that the ranks of $A$ and $C$ are the same?

Comment: It is a basic fact of linear algebra. The [(column) rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix is the dimension of the space spanned by the columns, or equivalently **the maximal number of independent columns**. Since $v$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_{i}$, the rank of $A$ and $C$ are the same.

Comment: I should add that **the maximal number of independent columns is independent of the field over which you are calculating it** - this is the point of the problem - you only need to take a field $E$ that contains the field $F$ containing the coefficients of the vectors/matrices. This can be seen from the alternative definition in terms of **determinantal rank** - look up the term in the [web page above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it’s true. Let $F=\mathbb Q$, $E=\mathbb R$, $n=2$, $\alpha_1=(1,0)$ and $\alpha_2=(0,1)$. Then $(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)=\sqrt2\alpha_1+\sqrt2\alpha_2$ is in the span of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ in $\mathbb R^2$ but not in the span of the vectors in $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: If $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $E=\mathbb{C}$ it is true?

Comment: So your vector $v$ is $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$? the assumption was that it is in $F^{n}$, though.

Comment: I was saying that $(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$ is in $E^n$ but not $F^n$; hence the “if” part is not true.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the "if" part says that a vector $v \in F^{n}$ is in the subspace of $F^{n}$ spanned by the $\alpha_{i}$ if $v$ is in the subspace of $E^{n}$ spanned by the $\alpha_{i}$.

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to show that the “if” part is not true.

Comment: You are missing the "$v \in F^{n}$" clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is true either, and intuitively so because it seems the converse is not powerful enough.

All you know is that $F \subseteq E$. The only assumption you have is that $x \in W$, where $W$ is a subspace of $E^n$. It is easy to construct an example such that not all of $W$ is in the subspace $F^n$ but all of it is in $E^n$ (you can even construct such that some vectors in $E^n$ have unique elements from the field $E$ but not $F$) , thus violating the proof.